# vim regular expression search and replace on range [a-z]+, etc

Tags: regex, search, vim, replace

I seem to have trouble finding resources on replacing ranges like [A-Za-z0-9] in vim.

Here is my example...

Search:

```
<h4>Text in Markup</h4>
```

After replace:

```
<h4><%= _t('Text in Markup') %></h4>
```

I am trying to do something like the following in Vim 7.4

```
:s/>([a-zA-Z\s]+)</><%= _t('$1') %></g
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, try this:

```
:s/\m<\(\w\+\)[^>]*>\zs[^<]\+\ze<\/\1>/<%= _t('&') %>/g
```

Decryption:

- `s/.../.../g` - substitute all on current line
- `\m` - turn on "magic" regexp syntax
- `\(...\)` - grouping
- `\w\+` - one or more word characters
- `[^>]*` - zero or more not-`>` characters (i.e. skip attributes)
- `\zs...\ze` - replace only what is matched between these points
- `[^<]\+` - one or more not-`<` characters
- `<\/\1>` - closing tag matching the opening one
- `&` - whatever is matched between `\zs` and `\ze`.

Answer (score 0):

A **very** simple solution:

```
:s/>\([^<]\+\)/><%= _t('\1') %></g
```

But be aware that it won't work if you have something (attributes, comments) containing `>` or `<`.